# c++ using 'this' in node tree

Tags: c++, tree, nodes

I make the root in main. Then in another .cpp I do something like

```
TreeNode * current = this;
```

then if I do

```
current = current->right;
```

so I can go down the tree. Will it change what 'this' refers to?

Comment: Pretty sure I figured it out. I made a changeThis() to try it myself and it didn't change anything in 'this'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it change what 'this' refers to?

**No**.

`current` is not an alias for `this`, and you cannot change the `this` pointer anyway.

Here is what you are doing. Assume `this` points to some object, and call that `OBJECT1`. In the beginning, you have this situation:

```
 [ this --------> OBJECT1 ] (this points to OBJECT1)
```

After you do this

```
 TreeNode * current = this;
```

You have this situation:

```
 [ this --------> OBJECT1 ] (this points to OBJECT1)
 [ current -----> OBJECT1 ] (current also points to OBJECT1)
```

After you do this...

```
 current = current->right;
```

You have this situation:

```
 [ this --------> OBJECT1 ] (this still points to OBJECT1)
 [ current -----> OBJECT2 ] (current now points to a different object)
```

Where `OBJECT2` is the object pointed or by `OBJECT1->right`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are *copying* the value of `this` to `current`.  Changing `current` won't affect `this`. You can't change the value of `this` in anyway.